# Rigid Body fps controller issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to make my own Rigid body character controller using Unity, I have movement but it's a little weird. When I press A/D it moves my Character along the x-axis, then when I press W/D it moves it along the y-axis. Also right now I have an fps camera (Brakeys) but the Rigid body has no code telling it to go in that direction.

Here is the code...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 5f;
public float jumpForce = 5f;
public bool isGrounded;
public Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    rb.AddForce(move * speed);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) when dealing with physics.

And you're assigning the vertical input value to the Y-axis. My guess is you want it on the Z-axis.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    rb.AddForce(move * speed);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I didn't expect to get an answer this fast.